# How can I solve this problem while creating recyclerview?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i'm trying to create `Recyclerview`+ `Cardview` with `GridLayout`
but Android Studio show me an error,
i need to know what is the wrong here
[A picture showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ddVb.png),
the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="190dp"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
cardview:cardcornerRadius="4dp">
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/book_img_id"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="160dp"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:background="#2d2d2d"/>
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/book_title_id"
  android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
  android:textSize="13sp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:text="سكر"/>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"` instead of `cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"`

`cardCornerRadius` attribute is under app

Try code like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Android"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you very much , but the probleam still found